# Calling an asp net core endpoint that takes both a file and a DTO

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to call the following endpoint from a C# console application:

```
public class TestDto
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("test")]
public async IActionResult Test([FromForm]IFormFile file, [FromForm]TestDto dto)
{
    return Ok("got it");
}
```

I managed to get it working with the following code, but it seems strange that I have to create a new StringContent for each property in the DTO:

```
var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();

var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\data.tar"));
fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
formData.Add(fileContent, "file", "data.tar");

var dto = new TestDto { Property1 = "hello", Property2 = "World"};

var jsonObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(JsonSerializer.Serialize(dto));
foreach (var property in jsonObject.EnumerateObject())
{
    formData.Add(new StringContent(property.Value.ToString()), property.Name);
}

var client = new HttpClient();

var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5264/upload/test", formData);
```

Isn't there a way to just take the Dto, and add it to the `MultipartFormDataContent` directly?

For example the following does not work (the endpoint hits, but all properties of the DTO are set to default values):

```
var dtoContent = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(dto));
dtoContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
formData.Add(dtoContent, "dto");
```

Comment: I find a lot about this, You always need to specify the property names manually. So I don't think you can just pass the whole DTO into HttpContent. You can custom model binding in your backend, But I think it's more troublesome than what you're doing now.